# Finding averages in an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that gets parts from a 2d array, averages them, and then prints it out.

the array looks like this:

```
data = [['Name:','John','Score:','6'],['Name:','John','Score:','8'],['Name:','John','Score:','6']]
```

How can I get the averages of the score?

Edit 1:

```
def average():
    print("\n\nAverage Scores: ")
    length = len(data)
    ind = 0
    data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    sav2 = []
    while length != 0:
        name = data[ind][1]
        counted = sum(x.count(name) for x in log)
        counting = counted
        av = 0
        while counting != 0:
            av += int(data[ind][3])
            ind += 1
            counting -= 1
        av = str(av/counted)
        sav2.append(("Name: "+name+" Average Score: "+av).split())
        length -= int(counted)
    sav2.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[4]), reverse = True)
    for word in sav2:
        wordJoin = ' '.join(word)
        print(wordJoin)
```

Here's some code that I borrowed from a friend, It works fine, but I don't understand it. Is there anything you guys can do with this?

Comment: Please show us testcases (expected output for defined input) and your try at solving a problem.

Comment: @VivekSable That's what I'm hoping for.

Comment: @Pokeguy35: check below all answers. where you define `data` variable in code? you are using `data` variable;e in this line `length = len(data)` .  Just post `data` value i.e. input of your code on you question or pass vivekbsable@gmail.com. Go with simple solution first, above code is too much for beginner

Comment: Did not know you could borrow code!

Answer (score 1):

You should show the others any of your trials. Also, as tobias_k mentioned in his comment, you should probably use dictionary.

Quick answer to your question:

```
summation, count = 0, 0
for i in data:
    summation += float(i[3])
    count += 1
averageResult = summation / count
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example:

```
sum([int(i[3]) for i in data])/3.0
```

instead of `3.0` you can use `float(len(data))`

if the numbers in your array are not integers then:

```
sum([float(i[3]) for i in data])/len(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find average now as

```
>>>sum([int(i[-1]) for i in data])/float(len(data))
6.666666
```

Answer (score 0):

According current data

1. Convert list datastructure to Dictionary.
2. Use`collection` module for that.
3. Iterate every item from the dictionary and calculate avg of scores.

Demo:

```
>>> import collections
>>> student_record = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> data = [['Name:','John','Score:','6'],['Name:','John','Score:','8'],['Name:','John','Score:','6']]
>>> for i in data:
...    student_record[i[1]].append(int(i[3]))
... 
>>> student_record
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'John': [6, 8, 6]})
>>> for i,j in student_record.items():
...     print "Name: %s, Score: %s, Avg: %s"%(i, j, float(sum(j))/len(j))
... 
Name: John, Score: [6, 8, 6], Avg: 6.66666666667
>>>
```

---

Changed Input structure to dictionary of list.

```
>>> import collections
>>> student_record = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> data = [{'Name':'John','Score':'6'},{'Name':'John','Score':'8'},{'Name':'John','Score':'6'}]
>>> for i in data:
...   student_record[i["Name"]].append(int(i["Score"]))
... 
>>> student_record
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'John': [6, 8, 6]})
>>> for i,j in student_record.items():
...     print "Name: %s, Score: %s, Avg: %s"%(i, j, float(sum(j))/len(j))
... 
Name: John, Score: [6, 8, 6], Avg: 6.66666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's best to approach these kinds of problems with as general a solution as possible as it best shows the concept behind it.  With that in mind:

We want a script that takes a 2D array and returns the average of a specific column.  Our function should thus take in the 2D array and a column-index

```
def averageOfColumn(people, columnIndex):
    #code
    return answer;
```

The mean is defined as the sum divided by n, so we want to find the sum of a column, and then divide by the number of people.  The sum of a column can be found as

```
answer = 0
for person in people:
    answer += person[columnIndex]
```

if we divide this sum by the number of people, we have our answer

```
def averageOfColumn(people, columnIndex):
    answer = 0;
    for person in people:
        answer += person[columnIndex];
    return answer / len(people);
```

We're not *quite* done yet, since your data is given as strings and we want it as a float or an int (so we can do math on it), so we have to make a slight alteration and cast the 'data' to a number-type

```
def averageOfStatistic(people, columnIndex):
    summation = 0;
    for person in people:
        summation += float(person[columnIndex]);
    return summation / len(people);
```

Or, in more generic-terms:

```
def averageOfStatistic(data, columnIndex):
    summation = 0;
    for point in data:
        summation += float(point[columnIndex]);
    return summation / len(data);
```

So finally we have

```
def averageOfStatistic(data, columnIndex):
    summation = 0;
    for point in data:
        summation += float(point[columnIndex]);
    return summation / len(data);

data = [['Name:','John','Score:','6'],['Name:','John','Score:','8'],['Name:','John','Score:','6']]

print averageOfStatistic(data, 3); # print average score
```